# Regex to add trailing slash to a URL unless the URL is followed by a specific sub folder

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I want to add a trailing slash to a specific URL structure if the trailing slash is not present. This URL should be:

```
/product/product-#/
```

A further condition is that the trailing slash should not be added to the URL if the URL has subsequent sub folders. This URL should be:

```
/product/product-#/subfolder/subpage
```

The following example URLs should therefore end with a trailing slash:

```
/product/product-1 becomes /product/product-1/
/product/product-2 becomes /product/product-2/
/product/product-3 becomes /product/product-3/
/product/product-4/ remains /product/product-4/
```

The following example URLs should not therefore end with a trailing slash:

```
/product/product-1/subfolder/1456 remains /product/product1/subfolder/1456
/product/product-2/subfolder/6789 remains /product/product-2/subfolder/6789
```

My attempt [here](https://regex101.com/r/Y6sOLz/1) is not working, the slash following the subfolder is not registering in the non-capturing group.

```
\/(?!.*(?:subfolder\/[0-9]{4})$)[^\/]+$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^(\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*)\/?$
```

You need to use `$1/` in substitution part while doing url-rewriting.

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/pSHkBI/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^                   ##Matching from starting of value here.
(                   ##Starting capturing group from here.
  \/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*  ##Matching 1 slash followed by values till next slash comes.
                    ##Followed by slash and match all values till next slash comes
)                   ##Closing capturing group here.
\/?$                ##Matching optional / at the end of value here.
```

Comment: Thank you, this has me on the right track. How can I specify that the first subfolder to match has to be `/product/` rather than any free text?

Comment: @turbobork, ok try changing regex to `^(\/[^\/]*\/product)\/?$`?

Comment: I think that might be the wrong way round - `^(\/product\/[^\/]*)\/?$` seems to fit the bill, thank you.